# Linear functional $\mathscr{L}(E,F)$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $\mathscr{L}(E,F)$ denote the space of all linear functionals from $E \to F$. 
Let $\mathscr{C}(E,F)$ denote the space of continuous linear functionals from $E \to F$. My question:

- How to prove that $\mathscr{C}(E,F)$ is a subspace of $\mathscr{L}(E,F)$?
- For $T \in \mathscr{C}(E,F)$ define $$||T||=\inf \bigl\{ k\in\mathbb{R} \ :\ \forall x \in E, \ ||T(x)||_{F} \leq k||x||_{E}\bigr\}$$ Then how to show that above defines a norm on $\mathscr{C}(E,F)$?

Proving subspace is easy, I think since, if $f,g \in \mathscr{C}(E,F)$ then $\alpha\cdot f + \beta \cdot g \in \mathscr{C}(E,F)$ this carries on from the definition of continuity itself. But what about proving norm.

Detailed explanations will help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the assumption of continuity implies that $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is well-defined. We need to check the axioms.

Homogeneity ($\lVert aT\rVert=|a|\lVert T\rVert$) is a consequence of $\inf\{\lambda S\}=\lambda\inf S$ for $\lambda\geqslant 0$.

Let $T\in\mathcal C(E,F)$ be such that $\lVert T\rVert=0$. Then for all $k>0$ and all $x\in E$, $\lVert Tx\rVert_F\leqslant k\lVert x\rVert_E$, hence $T\equiv 0$.

For triangular inequality, let $S,T\in\mathcal C(E,F)$. For an integer $n$, consider $a_n,b_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $$\forall x\in E, \quad\lVert Sx\rVert\leqslant a_n\lVert x\rVert,\lVert Tx\rVert\leqslant b_n\lVert x\rVert,$$
and $a_n\leqslant \lVert S\rVert+1/n$, $b_n\leqslant \lVert T\rVert+1/n$. What about $\lVert (S+T)x\rVert$?

Answer (score 0):

with attention to $||T||=\inf \bigl\{ k\in\mathbb{R} \ :\ \forall x \in E, \ ||T(x)||_{F} \leq k||x||_{E}\bigr\}
$ k>0 so$0\le ||T||$
it will be remain to show $$||T_1+T_2||\le ||T_1||+||T_2||$$
$||(T_1+T_2)(x)||_F\le ||T_1(x)||_F+||T_2(x)||_F\le( k_1+k_2)||x||_E$
($k_1 $ and $ k_2$ are coresspond to inf of defintion of $T_1$and $T_2$)
so k correspond to $T_1+T_2$ will be $k\le k_1+k_2$
so

||T_1+T_2||\le ||T_1||+||T_2||